# Changing the footer text in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't seem to be able to change the footer text.  I've tried the sorted event as well but nothing happens.  All I want to do is display status messages.  Here is my code:

```
protected void PageSettings_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
  if (((GridView)sender).EditIndex > -1)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
  else
  {
    // tried this on sorted aswell but can't change footer text
    GridViewRow row = ((GridView)sender).FooterRow as GridViewRow;
    Label lblStatus = new Label{ ID="lblStatus", Text="Sorting Column <b>\"" + e.SortExpression + "\" " + e.SortDirection + "</b>"};
    row.Cells[0].Text = "Hello World"; //.Controls.Add(lblStatus);            
  }
}

protected void PageSettings_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row != null && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
  {

  }
  else if (e.Row != null && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
  {
    int count = e.Row.Cells.Count;
    for (int i = count - 1; i >= 1; i += -1)
    {
      e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = count;
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(new Literal { ID = "lblStatus" });
    // can't FindControl or change Literals either
    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Hello World"; // works here but not on sorting event
  }        
}

<asp:GridView ID="PageSettings" runat="server"
     AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
     AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
     AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
     ShowFooter="true" 
     DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourcePages"
     OnLoad="PageSettings_Load" 
     OnRowDataBound="PageSettings_DataBound"
     OnRowCreated="PageSettings_RowCreated"
     OnRowEditing="PageSettings_RowEditing" 
     OnRowCancelingEdit="PageSettings_RowCancelingEdit"      
     OnPageIndexChanging="PageSettings_PageIndexChanging"
     OnSorting="PageSettings_Sorting" 
     OnSorted="PageSetting_Sorted"    
     PageSize="2">        
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Page Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Name">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Name") %>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>                
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Path" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Path">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Path") %>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>                    
        <asp:TextBox ID="Path" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Path") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Route Value" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="RouteValue">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("RouteValue") %>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="RouteValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RouteValue") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RegExp" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="RegExp">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("RegExp") %>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="RegExp" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegExp") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>                
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Post Markup of GridView so we can justify/determine what content a footer has.

Comment: Why do you want to do it during your sorting event? Surely you'd want to do it in a created/bound event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the text of the first `FooterRow` cell:

```
protected void gv_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    gv.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = "Hello";
}
```

Of course you'll need to make sure your `GridView`'s `ShowFooter` property is true.

Or alternatively, by casting sender and adding a control:

```
protected void Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = gv_s.Rows.Count.ToString() + " records";
    ((GridView)sender).FooterRow.Cells[0].Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what ive already got up on my example. it doesn't work

Comment: It works on my end. I assume you've tried firing the Sorting event to see the results?

Comment: For some reason my footer won't add text to any of my cells any ideas

Comment: Assuming your GridView has ShowFooter="true", what happens when you use gridview_id.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = "Hello"; in say Page_Load?

Comment: it adds text but doesn't add text on Sorting event

Comment: It does in my project, but only when I fire the Sorting event by clicking on the GridView header first. Is your sort being performed but the text isn't showing? That's strange.